# Puppeteer too much CPU

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cpu-usage

I'm trying to start this script that takes care of making visits to a site with different IPs through a proxy pool but after a few visits the CPU rises to 100% and begins to slow down more and more, you could help me to optimize it.

I state that I am not a programmer and I thank anyone who can help me solve this problem

```html
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const validUrl = require('valid-url');

const parseUrl = function (url) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url)
    if (!/^(?:f|ht)tps?:\/\//.test(url)) {
        url = 'https://' + url;
    }

    return url;
};
const getRandomDevice = () => {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const devices = Object.entries(puppeteer.devices)

    return devices[Math.floor(Math.random() * devices.length)][1]
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // const url = parseUrl(req.query.url);
    const url = 'https://www.example.com';
    const tries = req.query.tries || 100000;

    if (validUrl.isWebUri(url)) {
        console.log('Handling: ' + url);
        (async () => {
            const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless: true,
                // userDataDir: './myUserDataDir',
                args: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                    '--proxy-server=EXAMPLE-POOL-PROXY:13012'
                ]
            });

            let [page] = await browser.pages();

            for (let i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
                // enable request interception
                await page.setRequestInterception(true);

                const device = getRandomDevice()
                await page.setUserAgent(device.userAgent);
                await page.setViewport(device.viewport)

                // add header for the navigation requests
                page.on('request', request => {
                    // Add a new header for navigation request.
                    const headers = request.headers();
                    headers['User-Agent'] = device.userAgent;
                    headers['user-agent'] = device.userAgent;
                    request.continue({headers});
                });

                await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 1500000});

                try {
                    //console.log(page);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                } finally {
                    // console.log(urls);
                    // console.log(await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies'));

                    // await page.screenshot().then(function (buffer) {
                    //     res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="' + url + '.png"');
                    //     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
                    //     res.send(buffer)
                    // });
                    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot-' + i + '.png',fullPage: true})

                    // If everything correct then no 'HeadlessChrome' sub string on userAgent
                    console.log(await page.evaluate(() => navigator.userAgent));
                    page = await browser.newPage();
                }
            }

            setTimeout(async () => {
                await browser.close();
            }, 500);
        })();
    } else {
        res.send('Invalid url: ' + url);
    }

});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port ' + port)
})
```

Comment: Welcome. Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Could it be because you seem to be looping 100000 times

Comment: An alternative would be to run it from a server. eg: AWS Elastic Beanstalk.